# <Span> in table is bold/strong in IE, but normal in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, html-table

I've scripted in 5 dapbles, using divs to position them right.
I checked in Chrome and IE, and the difference is that in IE, the text is in bold format, but in chrome it's normal. I've used the `<span>` attribute because my `<p>` has some graphic design that won't look good in a table, but looks good on the other places where i use it.

My code for table:

```
<dic class="elevraadet">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;"><b>Klasse</b></span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;"><b>Namn</b></span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;"><b>Verv</b></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">3ST</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Reynaldo Galaz</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Leiar</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">1ST</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Frida Vevle</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Nestleiar</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">2ST</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&Oslash;yvind Hartveit</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Skrivar</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">2EL</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Robin B. Myking</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Kasserar/vara for skrivar</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">2BU</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Gina Nordpoll</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">2IND</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Anders Skråmestø</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">1EL</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Thomas K. Fotland</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">1DH</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Nathalie P. Hartveit</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">1HS</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Tina-Marie S. Langeland</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">1TIPa</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Marcus W. Øye</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">1TIPb</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Bjørn Sebastian S. Rongved</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span style="font-size:12px;">Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>  
</table>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
.elevraadet
{
border:groove, #09F;
position:absolute;
left:30px;
}
```

So my question is, how do I fix this so that it won't be bold/strong in IE?
I've added two screenshots, one from [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SYuU.png):

[image]

and one from [IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb9LK.png):

[image]

Comment: Without seeing all the CSS used in the page, have you tried `.elevraadet span {font-weight:normal}` ?

Comment: Thank you, it worked :D the reason why i didn't psot the whole CSS was because it's huge, it's around 2000 lines.

Comment: also you put `dic` instead of `div`

Comment: the dic was a typo when i asked the question

Answer (score 1):

There are a two things to do here is try and reslove the problem.

Firstly to style a span it is good practice to use CSS rather than in-line styles.

So add this to your CSS file

`.elevraadet span
    {
       font-wieght: normal;
       font-size: 12px;
    }`

Secondly the CSS is not being called as the div tags are incorrect! (dic instead of div)

```
<div class="elevraadet">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td><span><b>Klasse</b></span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span><b>Namn</b></span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span><b>Verv</b></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>3ST</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Reynaldo Galaz</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Leiar</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>1ST</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Frida Vevle</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Nestleiar</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>2ST</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>&Oslash;yvind Hartveit</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Skrivar</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>2EL</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Robin B. Myking</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Kasserar/vara for skrivar</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>2BU</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Gina Nordpoll</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>2IND</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Anders Skråmestø</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>1EL</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Thomas K. Fotland</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>1DH</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Nathalie P. Hartveit</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>1HS</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Tina-Marie S. Langeland</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>1TIPa</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Marcus W. Øye</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span>1TIPb</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Bjørn Sebastian S. Rongved</span></td>
<td><span>&nbsp;</span></td>
<td><span>Styremedlem</span></td>
</tr>  
</table>
</div>
```